# Print the JSON in angular js, I can see in console, but not able to print the same

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am missing something very simple.

In my controller I am getting the JSON object.

```
app.controller("dashboardCtrl",  ["$scope","authFactory","$location", function($scope,authFactory,$location){
    var userObj = authFactory.getUserObj(userObj);
    console.log(userObj);
    $scope.userObj = userObj;

    var accessToken = authFactory.getAccessToken();
    console.log(accessToken);
    $scope.accessToken = accessToken;

    $scope.FBout = function(){
        FB.logout(function(response) {
            authFactory.clearCookie();
            $location.path("/");    
            $scope.$apply();
        });
    };
}]);
```

In the console, I get the response as follows

```
{"name":"Pavan Sudheendra","id":"539193599614696"}
```

The factory code for the same is as shown below:

```
app.factory("authFactory",["$cookies","$location",function($cookies,$location){
    var authFactory = {};

    authFactory.setAccessToken = function(accessToken){
        $cookies.put("accessToken",accessToken);
    }

    authFactory.getAccessToken = function(){
        return $cookies.get("accessToken");
    }

    authFactory.getUserObj = function(){
        var userObj = $cookies.get('userObj');

        if(userObj){
            return userObj;
        }
        else {
            console.log("error");
        }
    }

    authFactory.clearCookie = function(){
        $cookies.remove("accessToken");
        $cookies.remove("userObj");
    }

    authFactory.isAuthenticated = function(){
        var isLoggedIn=$cookies.get("accessToken")?true:false;
        return isLoggedIn;
    }

    return authFactory;
}]);
```

but I am trying to use that object, to print it in the front end. Like

```
<h1> this is dashboard {{accessToken}} {{userObj.name}} </h1>
```

I am sure I have included every controller and linked the factory to it, and the thing is I am able to print the accesstoken. However I can't print the name and id of it.

If I try to print `{{userObj}}`, the whole object will be printed. then if I try `{{userObj.name}}` then I should get the name value of that user object, right?

Comment: it should work. Please can you post a running code that reproduce the issue. It's not clear from the code that you are accessing correct scope.

Comment: Ok.. let me add the complete controller, factory code.. hang on a second

Comment: Hope this helps. if u require anything else.. i can give you other code too.
when i login. i am saving those data into cookies. so i want to access those data. in the other views.. thats it..

Comment: cookies store strings not objects

Comment: {"name":"Pavan Sudheendra","id":"539193599614696"} .

SO this is string? this is what i am getting when i console. it.. so this is an object.. i want to access the name and ID of it..

Comment: @charlietfl yes you are right.  Good catch!! That can be cause. Pavan can you covert json string back to object using `angular.fromJson()` method

Comment: i very new to this.. have no idea abt  how to do that

Comment: try `$scope.userObj = angular.fromJson(userObj)`

Comment: hey thanks alot Guys.. it worked.. Upvote for both of you..

Comment: @charlietfl Please post it as accepted answer to help for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, your cookie stores a string, not an object. You can get an object back from your JSON string using the `angular.fromJson` method.

```
$scope.userObj = angular.fromJson(userObj)
```

You could potentially simplify things further by using the `$cookies` service's `getObject` and `putObject` methods, letting Angular serialize and deserialize the object in the background.

Comment: Why not use `$cookies.getObject/putObject` and allow Angular to do the serialize/deserialize for you?